# How to reference 2d array?

Tags: arrays, rust, reference

Im trying to pass newly initialized 2d array of chars to the struct; It says that types do not match and I dont know how to do it properly;

[Screenshot of code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5MPd.png)

```
struct Entity<'a> {
    dimensions: Vec2,
    sprite: &'a mut[&'a mut [char]]
}

impl Entity {

    fn new<'a>() -> Self {

        let mut sp = [[' '; 3]; 4];
        for y in 0..sp.len() {
            for x in 0..sp[y].len() {
                sp[y][x] = '$';
            }
        }
    
        return Entity{dimensions: Vec2::xy(3, 4), sprite: &mut sp }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return a value which is referencing a local variable. `sp` will be dropped after `new`, so the reference will be invalid. The compiler will complain about this. Why don't you let entity own the sprite without a reference? The syntax would be `&'a mut [[&'a mut char; 3]; 4]`, but you'll get multiple issues with that.

Comment: @peterulb when im trying to make entity own the sprite it says that the size for values of type `[char]` cannot be known at compilation time, I'm pretty new to rust so I cant understand this part and how to avoid it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @salat_ yes the compiler needs to know the stack size for the array, just like you did in the function (length 4 and 3). A reference size is always known, so is vec (since it’s pointing to the heap). So specify the size or if unknown use a dynamic approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think theres a couple things going on.

1.) `&'a mut[&'a mut [char]]` references a mutable slice containing mutables slices of chars. What you are constructing is a fixed array matrix of chars and then attempting to return mutable references to that. These are not interchangeable types.

2.) You are attempting to return references to data created within `new`, which is not going to work like that due to the lifetime of the local variables.

An alternative, which might be what you want is to define your struct to contain a fixed size array matrix. Like so:

```
struct Entity {
    sprite: [[char; 3]; 4]
}

impl Entity {

    fn new() -> Self {
    
        let mut sp = [[' '; 3]; 4];
        for y in 0..sp.len() {
            for x in 0..sp[y].len() {
                sp[y][x] = '$';
            }
        }

        return Entity{sprite: sp }
    }
}
```

Or you could even use const generics for different sizes:

```
struct Entity<const W: usize, const H: usize> {
    sprite: [[char; W]; H]
}

 impl<const W: usize, const H: usize> Entity<W, H> {

     fn new() -> Self {
    
        let mut sp = [[' '; W]; H];
        for y in 0..sp.len() {
            for x in 0..sp[y].len() {
                sp[y][x] = '$';
            }
        }
    
        return Entity{sprite: sp }
    }
}
```

If you cannot know the size of the sprite at time of compilation, you will need to define it using a dynamically sized data structure, such as a `Vec`. Ie., `Vec<Vec<char>>`.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking exactly for that)